# pandas dataframe longest series with uninterrupted data

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a data-frame like

```
      A         B         C
0  1.232853 -1.979459  NaN
1  NaN       0.394940  1.068890
2  NaN       1.343977  NaN
3  2.125299 -0.649328 -0.211692
4 -0.187253  1.908618 -1.862934
5  2.243432  3.003434 NaN
```

I want to find for each column what is the longest series of uninterrupted data.
For col A it is rows 3:5, for B 0:5 and C 3,4.

Additionally, how I get the same idea over the whole data-frame ? In this case I'd get rows 3,4.

Answer (score 3):

You can first make a temporary DataFrame in which each series of uninterrupted data is labeled with a (per column) unique number. And place the 'original' NaN's back so the longest series cant be a series of NaN's.

```
dfseries = (df.notnull().shift(1) != df.notnull()).cumsum()
dfseries[df.isnull()] = np.nan

    A  B   C
0   1  1 NaN
1 NaN  1   2
2 NaN  1 NaN
3   3  1   4
4   3  1   4
5   3  1 NaN
```

To get the end result over the entire DataFrame, at this points you can add:

```
dfseries = dfseries.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
```

If you then do a GroupBy (per column) and a cumulative count per group, the maximum of that operation is the length of the longest series and the `idxmax` will be the position at which that series ends.

Put both in a new DataFrame with:

```
dfrng = pd.concat((dfseries.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(x.values).cumcount().max()),
                   dfseries.apply(lambda x: x.groupby(x.values).cumcount().idxmax())),
                   axis=1, keys=['Length', 'EndPos'])
```

The beginning of the series is then simply:

```
dfrng['StartPos'] = dfrng.EndPos - dfrng.Length
```

Since `cumcount` starts at zero, the length should be raised by one.

```
dfrng['Length'] = dfrng.Length + 1
```

Which for your example result in:

```
dfrng.T

          A  B  C
Length    3  6  2
EndPos    5  5  4
StartPos  3  0  3
```